# MySQL create one row from two or more resultsets

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a list of persons with the following fileds:

```
persons (id, identity, name, surname)
```

And then there is a second table with the following fields:

```
identities (id, type)
```

The values for the identities.type field could sexuality or affiliation in terms of whether a person is a traditional healer or not.

We have a third table where we have persons identity preferences and below is the mapping:

```
preferences (id, person_id, identity_id, value)
```

Say for example I identify as a Heterosexual guy and a traditional healer and then person 2 identifies as just homosexual.

Below is a representation of the scenario above:

[image]

If I want to eliminate the second row and add the second value field for the first user in the first row, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

A bit difficult without seeing the tables separetly, but that's my guess based on your description. Does this go into the right direction?

```
SELECT 
p.id, p.name, p.surname, pref.id, pref.person_id,
CASE WHEN i.type = 'sexuality' THEN p.value ELSE NULL END AS sexuality,
CASE WHEN i.type = 'affiliation' THEN p.value ELSE NULL END AS affiliation
FROM persons p
JOIN preferences pref ON p.id = pref.person_id
JOIN identities i ON i.id = pref.identity_id
```

Comment: This really came close to the solution except I am still left with duplicates on my result set. I think you have helped a lot in understanding how I can go about this and the honors are on to me to get it right. However, I am thinking of using an "IF" statement to get rid of the duplicates but it doesn't seem a viable solution. Would you perhaps suggest a trick I could use to get this done... Your solution was very helpful.

Comment: then maybe you need to do it with a subqueries

Comment: Is it safe to assume that per person there is one sexuality and one affiliation? if so, this could work for you:

`SELECT 
p.id, p.name, p.surname, pref.id, pref.person_id,
(SELECT value FROM preferences pref JOIN identities i ON i.id = pref.identity_id WHERE person_id = p.id AND i.type = 'sexuality' LIMIT 1) AS sexuality,
(SELECT value FROM preferences pref JOIN identities i ON i.id = pref.identity_id WHERE person_id = p.id AND i.type = 'affiliation' LIMIT 1) AS affiliation
FROM persons p`

Answer (score 0):

In the persons and identities table you have to insert every record just one time. But in the preferences table you can insert any combination of previous two tables how many times you want. Than you have to write a select statement with joins to display a table like in the picture:

```
SELECT * FROM preferences p
INNER JOIN persons u on u.id = p.person_id
INNER JOIN identities i on i.id = p.identity_id
```